# Stop Google Sheets from removing trailing zeros

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-filter

Can anyone suggest a Google Sheets formula to stop removing trailing zeros? (but allow truncating to 6 digits after decimal?  00.000000

29.9918650  -93.958005  29.991865   -93.958005  (1mi:29.991865:-93.958005)

GOOGLE DOC:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k4Xydv-VGmvIrwuidsmtXwUkGkSfJh0grmn4Pvh2qWQ/edit?usp=sharing

EXPLAINER VIDEO:
https://www.loom.com/share/81e77eecdff04dda802b19cf566ac1f9

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Exact copy of [Stop Google Sheets From Removing Trailing Zeros](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/253855111). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Answer (score 2):

You can use number formatting to set six decimal places. Click the **Increase decimal places** button <sup>**.00**</sup><sub>→</sub> button in the toolbar until you have six decimals.

Alternatively, format the pertinent cells explicitly as **Format > Number > Custom number format >** `0.0000000`.

You can copy and paste an existing number format from a cell to other cells with **Edit > Paste special > Format only**.

To set the number format with a *formula*, apply this pattern:

```
=query(trunc(D12, 6), "format Col1 '0.000000' ", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using the formula you gave, however, I noticed it needs to be applied to the last colum.  Can you assist me with understanding that part? 
VIDEO: https://www.loom.com/share/7e9f5064971343c2b89afc9290223639?sid=045cfae3-f648-44ee-b05f-8c946eb64275

Comment: Site best practices state that questions should be self-contained. Many contributors here will refuse to follow links to external sites. Many others will refuse to view videos. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead. Include all relevant details in the question.